# How to compare two columns in different sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have one excel file with multiple sheets.
I need to compare two sheets (1) TotalList and (2) cList with more than 25 columns, in these two sheets columns are same.

On cList the starting row is 3
On TotalList the starting row is 5

Now, I have to compare the E & F columns from cList, with TotalList E & F columns, if it is not found then add the entire row at the end of TotalList sheet and highlight with Yellow.

```
Public Function compare()  
    Dim LoopRang As Range  
    Dim FoundRang As Range  
    Dim ColNam  
    Dim TotRows As Long  

    LeaData = "Shhet2"
    ConsolData = "Sheet1"

    TotRows = Worksheets(LeaData).Range("D65536").End(xlUp).Row  
    TotRows1 = Worksheets(ConsolData).Range("D65536").End(xlUp).Row  
    'TotRows = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(LeaData).UsedRange.Rows.Count  
    ColNam = "$F$3:$F" & TotRows  
    ColNam1 = "$F$5:$F" & TotRows1  
    For Each LoopRang In Sheets(LeaData).Range(ColNam)  
        Set FoundRang = Sheets(ConsolData).Range(ColNam1).Find(LoopRang, lookat:=xlWhole)  
        For Each FoundRang In Sheets(ConsolData).Range(ColNam1)  
            If FoundRang & FoundRang.Offset(0, -1) <> LoopRang & LoopRang.Offset(0, -1) Then    
                TotRows = Worksheets(ConsolData).Range("D65536").End(xlUp).Row  
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(LeaData).Rows(LoopRang.Row).Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ConsolData).Rows(TotRows + 1)  
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ConsolData).Rows(TotRows + 1).Interior.Color = vbYellow  
                GoTo NextLine  
            End If  
        Next FoundRang  
NextLine:  
    Next LoopRang  

End Function
```

Please help with the VBA code.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: One path: http://superuser.com/a/496277/85273

Comment: @OP: please tell us what you already did so far. This isn't a free of charge scripting service this is for programmers who have a programming question because they are stuck or want to improve a script, things of that kind. So post us your script and tell us where you are stuck and we will try our best to help.

Comment: updated the code above, in the above code it is copying the data which have already in the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

First I am going to give some general coding hints:

1. set Option Explicit ON. This is done through Tools > Options >
   Editor (tab) > Require Variable Declaration . Now you HAVE to
   declare all variables before you use them.
2. always declare a variables type when you declare it. If you are unsure about what to sue or if it can take different types (not advisable!!) use `Variable`.
3. Use a standard naming convention for all your variables. Mine is a string starts with `str` and a double with `dbl` a range with `r`, etc.. So `strTest`, `dblProfit` and `rOriginal`. Also give your variables MEANINGFUL names!
4. Give your Excel spreadsheets meanigful names or captions (caption is what you see in excel, name is the name you can directly refer to in VBA). Avoid using the caption, but refer to the name instead, as users can change the caption easily but the name only if they open the VBA window.

---

Ok so here is how a comparison between two tables can be done with your code as starting point:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function Compare()

        Dim rOriginal As Range          'row records in the lookup sheet (cList = Sheet2)
        Dim rFind As Range              'row record in the target sheet (TotalList = Sheet1)
        Dim rTableOriginal As Range     'row records in the lookup sheet (cList = Sheet2)
        Dim rTableFind As Range         'row record in the target sheet (TotalList = Sheet1)
        Dim shOriginal As Worksheet
        Dim shFind As Worksheet
        Dim booFound As Boolean

        'Initiate all used objects and variables
        Set shOriginal = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
        Set shFind = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set rTableOriginal = shOriginal.Range(shOriginal.Rows(3), shOriginal.Rows(shOriginal.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        Set rTableFind = shFind.Range(shFind.Rows(5), shFind.Rows(shFind.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        booFound = False

        For Each rOriginal In rTableOriginal.Rows
            booFound = False
            For Each rFind In rTableFind.Rows
                'Check if the E and F column contain the same information
                If rOriginal.Cells(1, 5) = rFind.Cells(1, 5) And rOriginal.Cells(1, 6) = rFind.Cells(1, 6) Then
                    'The record is found so we can search for the next one
                    booFound = True
                    GoTo FindNextOriginal 'Alternatively use Exit For
                End If
            Next rFind

            'In case the code is extended I always use a boolean and an If statement to make sure we cannot
            'by accident end up in this copy-paste-apply_yellow part!!
            If Not booFound Then
                'If not found then copy form the Original sheet ...
                rOriginal.Copy
                '... paste on the Find sheet and apply the Yellow interior color
                With rTableFind.Rows(rTableFind.Rows.Count + 1)
                    .PasteSpecial
                    .Interior.Color = vbYellow
                End With
                'Extend the range so we add another record at the bottom again
                Set rTableFind = shFind.Range(rTableFind, rTableFind.Rows(rTableFind.Rows.Count + 1))
            End If

FindNextOriginal:
        Next rOriginal

End Function
```